# Android Studio 2.0 does not load after update

Tags: android-studio, updates

I updated my Android Studio to 2.0, after that it doesn't open.

After completing the check for SDK, nothing is happening.

I tried uninstall, install studio 1.5 and updated again, but same result.

My OS is windows 10, in Dell Laptop.

Any help is appreciated.